# VB DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize

Tags: vb.net

I have set my default paper size depending on the choice.

But it always uses the printer default not the one that I pick.

```
If papel_cmb.SelectedItem = "et" Then
    PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(papel_cmb.SelectedIndex)
ElseIf papel_cmb.SelectedItem = "etc" Then
    PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(papel_cmb.SelectedIndex)
End If
PrintDocument1.Print()
```

Here I get all the papersizes. I'm only writing the paper names on the combo box so its more user friendly, but the paper sizes are being stored in an array.

```
Dim pnome As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    If impre.SelectedItem <> "" Then
        papel_cmb.Items.Clear()
        PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = impre.SelectedItem
        ReDim papeis(PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count)
        For Each papel As PaperSize In PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes
            pnome = papel.PaperName
            If Not papel_cmb.Items.Contains(pnome) Then
                papel_cmb.Items.Add(pnome)
                papeis(i) = papel
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
        papel_cmb.SelectedItem = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.PaperName
        papel_cmb.Enabled = True
    End If
```

Comment: Your if/elseif do exactly the same thing.  If the selected item is not et/etc you don't appear to do anything at all?

Comment: yes i know my else if does the same thing my bad...if its diferent from et/etc its suppose to do nothing